# What has changed in Google wallet in-app API?

Tags: in-app-purchase, android-pay

What has happened to the Google jsapi for inapp purchases?  This code worked 2 days ago and stopped working yesterday.

I load the script from [here](http://www.google.com/jsapi)

and then load the payments:

```
 google.load('payments', '1.0', {
        'packages': ['sandbox_config']

    });
```

Then when I call the purchase:

```
goog.payments.inapp.buy({ etc ...
```

I get is a script error 'goog' is undefined.

Comment: The plot thickens ... Do I have to include jQuery before I call in-app?  
Anyway -- I have traced thru the google code and find that goog should be "window.parent.google".

What has changed??

Comment: jQuery isn't needed for in-app. Could just have been a **sandbox** "hiccup"(?). Seems all's well in [my sandbox](http://code.edchavez.com/simple_demo)

Comment: OK -- WORKS IN CHROME. FAILS IN Internet Explorer 9!!!

Comment: Interesting - I don't recall the reason I'm forcing IE8 via `X-UA-Compatible` but it seems things work if I debug using IE9 on IE9 browser and document modes...

Comment: I just removed the `X-UA-Compatible` directive I had forcing the page to ie8 so things should work as expected on ie9. [MSDN reference on document modes is here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Thanks Ed, but I made a mistake.  This was Win 8 / IE 10 that I am running..  Still doesn't work on that!

Comment: I added a    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=9" /> and got Line: 351  Error: Class$S1674: Must provide a target window

Comment: Can't provide input at this time - I don't have win8/ie10...sorry...where's your page (url)?

Comment: I'm testing only -- do not have a deplyment

Comment: I apologize but I see this exact same error using Chrome.  This is in production and it was working since Google IO 2012.  I added support right after learning about the new google wallet api at IO.  To see the error go to http://signup.runnyc.com/evententry/2929162  fill in all required fields (you can put "x" in the fields, email requires something that looks like an email address "x@x.com" works and you must check the accept waiver box.   When you click on "pay with google wallet" you will see Uncaught ReferenceError: goog is not defined

Comment: i posted an answer to my issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13769248/google-wallet-inapp-payments-uncaught-referenceerror-goog-is-not-defined-goog/13769419#13769419