# google wallet inapp payments: Uncaught ReferenceError: goog is not defined. google.payments vs goog.payments

Tags: in-app-purchase, android-pay

we've been using google wallet inapp-payments since google io 2012.

Recently we see this error:

Uncaught ReferenceError: goog is not defined

The code is very simple:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load('payments', '1.0', {

    'packages': ['production_config']

  })
```

Then we use the jquery document.ready callback to call goog.payments.inapp.buy, but it seems that the goog object is not created by then.  This seems to be a race condition.  purchase function simply calls goog.payments.inapp.buy

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
      purchase('Item1'); //function to call goog.payments.inapp.buy
       });
```

It is also confusing because this page https://sandbox.google.com/checkout/customer/gadget/inapp/demo.html shows the call to buy is:

```
google.payments.inapp.buy
```

while this page https://developers.google.com/in-app-payments/docs/tutorial#3 shows the call to buy is:

```
goog.payments.inapp.buy
```

Answer (score 0):

After some additional searching (also because of the process of writing the question) a solution has been found:

See https://developers.google.com/in-app-payments/docs/tutorial#3

> Important: If the API library hasn't loaded, the call to buy() will
>   fail. You can avoid this problem by specifying the button onClick
>   handler in step 3, using the Google Loader callback option. For
>   details on using optional settings with google.load(), see the Google
>   Loader Developer's Guide.

It is important to use the callback of the google.load call in order to avoid race conditions.

```
google.load('payments', '1.0', {
  'packages': ['production_config']

  ,"callback": function() {
          // wait for goog object to exist before using it.
          //goog.payments.inapp.buy(...);
   }
  }
```